# Direct Update Failure in MobileFirst Application 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have migrated a Worklight 6.1 application to MobileFirst 7.0 platform. I am having issues with the direct update. The issue is, when I make some changes in the code and upload the wlapp on the server and run the application on the device (application does not contain the changes) the direct update pop-up arrives but, it shows the message:

> Direct update fails

Following are the logs:

```
11-25 16:51:45.693: D/ViewRootImpl(10979): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-25 16:51:45.863: D/NONE(10979): Login : Start
11-25 16:51:45.863: D/NONE(10979): Authenticate : Start
11-25 16:51:45.873: D/NONE(10979): Request [login]
11-25 16:51:45.913: W/PluginManager(10979): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 45ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
11-25 16:51:45.953: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): Constructing
11-25 16:51:45.963: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name X-Requested-With value XMLHttpRequest
11-25 16:51:45.973: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name Accept value text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
11-25 16:51:45.973: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name Accept-Language value en-GB
11-25 16:51:45.973: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name Content-type value application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
11-25 16:51:45.983: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-app-version value 6.0.0
11-25 16:51:45.983: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-platform-version value 7.0.0.0
11-25 16:51:45.983: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name encryption_enabled value Y
11-25 16:51:45.993: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name X-WL-ClientId value bd5de8c9982de6da334fd03915af40a6c3325c2b
11-25 16:51:45.993: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name X-WL-Session value 8b6fb884-d8fb-424f-99b9-166676ff2395
11-25 16:51:45.993: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): send
11-25 16:51:46.003: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin.execute in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:52 :: execute
11-25 16:51:46.003: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin.doSend in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:72 :: doSend
11-25 16:51:46.003: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74086(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
11-25 16:51:46.003: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74086(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
11-25 16:51:46.013: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74086(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
11-25 16:51:46.013: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74086(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
11-25 16:51:46.013: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74086(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
11-25 16:51:49.153: D/com.worklight.wlclient.WorklightRedirectHandler(10979): Jdk14Logger.log in Jdk14Logger.java:103 :: Redirect requested to location '/'
11-25 16:51:49.503: I/System.out(10979): pool-7-thread-1 calls detatch()
11-25 16:51:49.523: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onResponse in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:133 :: onResponse
11-25 16:51:49.523: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.buildResponseJSON in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:188 :: buildResultJSON
11-25 16:51:49.533: D/NONE(10979): isCustomResponse : status200
11-25 16:51:49.543: D/NONE(10979): isCustomResponse : response returned isfalse
11-25 16:51:49.553: D/NONE(10979): establishSSLClientAuth
11-25 16:51:49.563: D/wl.userAuthManager(10979): WLUserAuthManager.doesValidCertificateExist in WLUserAuthManager.java:129 :: doesValidCertificateExists = false
11-25 16:51:49.573: D/NONE(10979): establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
11-25 16:51:49.573: D/NONE(10979): Request [/apps/services/api/myApp/android/query]
11-25 16:51:49.583: D/WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_MANAGER(10979): skinLoaderChecksum does not exists.
11-25 16:51:49.583: D/NONE(10979): Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.0.0.0","nativeVersion":"3862182565","skinName":"default","skinChecksum":1416210609}}
11-25 16:51:49.593: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): Constructing
11-25 16:51:49.593: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): open method POST url /apps/services/api/myApp/android/query
11-25 16:51:49.613: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name X-Requested-With value XMLHttpRequest
11-25 16:51:49.613: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name Accept value text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
11-25 16:51:49.613: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name Accept-Language value en-GB
11-25 16:51:49.613: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name Content-type value application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
11-25 16:51:49.613: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-app-version value 6.0.0
11-25 16:51:49.623: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-app-details value {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.0.0.0","nativeVersion":"3862182565","skinName":"default","skinChecksum":1416210609}}
11-25 16:51:49.623: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-clientlog-deviceId value d07d57d2b56d48cd
11-25 16:51:49.623: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-clientlog-appname value myApp
11-25 16:51:49.633: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-clientlog-appversion value 6.0.0
11-25 16:51:49.633: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-clientlog-osversion value 5.1.1
11-25 16:51:49.633: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-clientlog-env value android
11-25 16:51:49.633: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name x-wl-clientlog-model value SM-G925I
11-25 16:51:49.643: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name X-WL-ClientId value bd5de8c9982de6da334fd03915af40a6c3325c2b
11-25 16:51:49.643: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): setRequestHeader name X-WL-Session value 8b6fb884-d8fb-424f-99b9-166676ff2395
11-25 16:51:49.643: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): send
11-25 16:51:49.643: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin.execute in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:52 :: execute
11-25 16:51:49.653: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin.doSend in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:72 :: doSend
11-25 16:51:49.653: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74087(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
11-25 16:51:49.653: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74087(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
11-25 16:51:49.653: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74087(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
11-25 16:51:49.653: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74087(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
11-25 16:51:50.173: I/System.out(10979): pool-7-thread-2 calls detatch()
11-25 16:51:50.173: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onResponse in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:133 :: onResponse
11-25 16:51:50.173: D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10979): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.buildResponseJSON in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:188 :: buildResultJSON
11-25 16:51:50.183: D/WLNativeXHR(10979): callback {"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized","responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"challenges\":{\"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm\":{\"token\":\"a9h78od99l5l1850rtuahju0ud\"},\"wl_directUpdateRealm\":{\"skinChecksum\":3598180860,\"unpackedSize\":6412960,\"packedSize\":1917007,\"directUpdateLink\":\"directUpdate\\/myApp\\/android\\/6.0.0\\/3598180860\\/full\\/default\"},\"wl_antiXSRFRealm\":{\"WL-Instance-Id\":\"un44hbeop6251l651f612q9fe4\"}}}*/\n","headers":{"X-Backside-Transport":"FAIL FAIL","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","P3P":"policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"","WWW-Authenticate":"WL-Composite-Challenge","Content-Type":"application/json","Expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","Pragma":"no-cache","Content-Language":"en-US","Date":"Wed, 25 Nov 2015 11:21:50 GMT","X-Client-IP":"14.140.116.145","X-Global-Transaction-ID":"247758999"}}
11-25 16:51:50.223: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
11-25 16:51:50.223: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
11-25 16:51:50.223: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032a}
11-25 16:51:50.233: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032b}
11-25 16:51:50.233: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032c}
11-25 16:51:50.243: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032d}
11-25 16:51:50.253: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032e}
11-25 16:51:50.253: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020332}
11-25 16:51:50.263: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020333}
11-25 16:51:50.263: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020334}
11-25 16:51:50.263: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032f}
11-25 16:51:50.273: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020330}
11-25 16:51:50.293: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020331}
11-25 16:51:50.313: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
11-25 16:51:50.313: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
11-25 16:51:50.353: D/SRIB_DCS(10979): log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
11-25 16:51:50.353: D/mali_winsys(10979): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x851]-format:1
11-25 16:51:52.713: D/ViewRootImpl(10979): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-25 16:51:52.803: E/ViewRootImpl(10979): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
11-25 16:51:52.803: W/System.err(10979): stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.myApp/files/assets.zip
11-25 16:51:52.803: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74088(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
11-25 16:51:52.803: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74088(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
11-25 16:51:52.803: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74088(ApacheHTTPLog):SMARTBONDING_ENABLED is false
11-25 16:51:52.803: I/System.out(10979): Thread-74088(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
11-25 16:51:52.803: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(10979): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.downloadZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:142 :: 0 bytes are already available. 
11-25 16:51:52.803: D/WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_MANAGER(10979): DirectUpdateManager.startUpdate.onDirectUpdateSuccess: {"operation":"start","totalSize":1917007}
11-25 16:51:52.813: D/WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_CHALLENGE_HANDLER(10979): defaultListener.onStart: totalSize=1917007
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102033a}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102033b}
11-25 16:51:52.843: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
11-25 16:51:52.843: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032a}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032b}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032c}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032d}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032e}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020332}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020333}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020334}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032f}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020330}
11-25 16:51:52.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020331}
11-25 16:51:52.863: W/PluginManager(10979): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLDirectUpdatePlugin.showProgressDialog blocked the main thread for 54ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
11-25 16:51:52.863: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
11-25 16:51:52.863: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
11-25 16:51:52.883: D/SRIB_DCS(10979): log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
11-25 16:51:52.893: D/mali_winsys(10979): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1336x723]-format:1
11-25 16:51:53.273: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(10979): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.downloadZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:151 :: The server returned file different than expected application update zip file
11-25 16:51:56.753: I/System.out(10979): AsyncTask #5 calls detatch()
11-25 16:51:56.763: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(10979): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.downloadZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:152 :: Response Data: PK???????yG??????????????????????????????default/css/??PK??????????????????????PK???????yG??????????????????????????????default/css/myApp.cssMPAn?0<)?c??Bi?J?H?-????????v?J-?%??g')3T~??Z"a?'??? ?+???#??S?sP????l?DV&e6[dI?jO?j?c?'?#l???.M&X>???q???=?Y?[????|6{???aQ`?5w8?#??,????^?M??;?Y ,\)yD??C????????H?n`?#6?
11-25 16:51:56.763: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(10979): ??=*?4W?<??o????T?o?ú??!??t?K??????D???]g?{L7j??PK?6???????????PK???????yG??????????????????????????????default/filelist?\]w?8}???=?????N???tNwz?#?Jb$a???$??U$/?-?{KR?T??1?{Q?{?GQ+(x??
11-25 16:51:56.763: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(10979): ?0??ZT??f-2U???8??65?+}??H-??
11-25 16:51:56.763: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(10979): U???E7???C?Ls?Z???k?
??G???]+??[???W??f??o{`O?T,?zU?-?;0??Z?#??ZU'?QR?p?Q5?5???8?]??T?T?+n???$o??/?????HE????~?27??#B??Rx<A??$?X?r??2?^`????{z??=o?6?}o?]??v?m.?U???N/??umH???'??RrK2?3?62ppu?(?H?X??f$?@???%??A?AY??j?v9:??O
????^?'?KE??x?~K?MO?W??)z?F??p??????sA????;4^?!??l?8$;{?)3i`?m??=??????W/?1?)?? ?p<??;8^]?[J???xupY?x:RHV(???G+&(???E?R????N?k0"?-5??)???%i?<?????:<^_??I??
11-25 16:51:56.763: D/WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_MANAGER(10979): DirectUpdateManager.startUpdate.onDirectUpdateSuccess: {"operation":"finish","status":"FAILURE_UNKNOWN"}
11-25 16:51:56.773: D/WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_CHALLENGE_HANDLER(10979): defaultListener.onFinish: status=FAILURE_UNKNOWN
11-25 16:51:56.773: D/WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_CHALLENGE_HANDLER(10979): defaultListener.onFinish: hideProgressDialog
11-25 16:51:56.783: W/PluginManager(10979): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLDirectUpdatePlugin.hideProgressDialog blocked the main thread for 19ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
11-25 16:51:56.783: E/ViewRootImpl(10979): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
11-25 16:51:56.813: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
11-25 16:51:56.813: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032a}
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032b}
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032c}
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x105010c}
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x105010c}
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x105010c}
11-25 16:51:56.813: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032d}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020332}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020333}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x105010c}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x105010c}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x1020334}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x102032f}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1001 a=1 r=0x1050115}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x601 a=1 r=0x1050114}
11-25 16:51:56.823: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x601 a=1 r=0x1050114}
11-25 16:51:56.833: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x2a01 a=1 r=0x1050117}
11-25 16:51:56.833: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x2401 a=1 r=0x1050116}
11-25 16:51:56.833: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x105011a}
11-25 16:51:56.833: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x105011a}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x2a01 a=1 r=0x1050117}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x2401 a=1 r=0x1050116}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x105011a}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x105011a}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x2a01 a=1 r=0x1050117}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x2401 a=1 r=0x1050116}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x105011a}
11-25 16:51:56.843: W/Resources(10979): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x105011a}
11-25 16:51:56.863: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
11-25 16:51:56.863: D/PhoneWindow(10979): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
11-25 16:51:56.913: D/SRIB_DCS(10979): log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
11-25 16:51:56.913: D/mali_winsys(10979): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1528x1009]-format:1
11-25 16:52:00.013: D/ViewRootImpl(10979): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-25 16:52:00.133: D/wl.splashscreen(10979): WLSplashScreen.hide in WLSplashScreen.java:71 :: Hiding Splash Screen
11-25 16:52:00.133: E/ViewRootImpl(10979): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: What is your exact MFP 7.0 build version? The logs show that an attempt is made to resume the direct update but this fails because a valid zip did not arrive from the server.
Is this consistently reproducible? Even if you uninstall the application and try again?

Comment: The build version and wlapp version are same. It is constantly reproducible. Even if I uninstall and again install the app.

Comment: This is not what Vivin asked you, @KushThapar. He asked you *what is the MFP version and build number that you are using*. Open the Console and go to the About screen. What does it show there?

Comment: Version - 7.0.0.00-20150907-1450.

Answer (score 0):

Did this work in the past? Did it start failing only recently?
Does it work in iOS 8 but fails in iOS 9?

There is a recent APAR that corrected a permissions issue in iOS that otherwise caused Direct Update failure. My recommendation to you thus is to ugrade to the latest available Studio iFix from IBM Fix Central, containing the following APAR: PI52444 DIRECT UPDATE FAILED DUE TO PERMISSION ISSUE ON IOS DEVICES

Comment: Thanks Idan but, I am facing this issue with android also.

Comment: Then please open a PMR.

Comment: Whenever I upload the wlapp I get the following warnings.

Environment: android of application has been deployed with a different version of the native MobileFirst SDK. Direct updates will no longer be available for existing clients with other versions of the MobileFirst SDK. To continue to use direct updates, increment the app version, publish it to the public app store, deploy to the server and  block/notify older versions of the app to enforce customers to upgrade to the new version from the app store.