# Direct Update Failed for Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Migrated application from 6.2 to 7.0. Server MobileFirst version: 7.0.0.00.20150312-0731

The application itself works great. When push new wlapp to server, the device see's update is available. Proceed to install update and fails.

logCat

> W/PluginManager(11315): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLDirectUpdatePlugin.start blocked the main thread for 20ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   W/HardwareRenderer(11315): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
>   W/PluginManager(11315): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLDirectUpdatePlugin.showProgressDialog blocked the main thread for 44ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader( 9466): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.validateZipFileIntegrity in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:129 :: Invalid direct update zip file, original file might have been altered or replaced.

Comment: In LogCat does it say what type  of file was downloaded? It should be "application/zip."

Comment: Is this only happening in Android?

Comment: @DoraC added more logs. I see this blocked thread warning. Would that cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

7.0.0.00.20150312-0731 is an awfully old build of MFPF 7.0; many fixes, including to Direct Update took place since.

I suggest that you will update to latest available iFix from IBM Fix Central to confirm this issue still happens to you.

Comment: This was our test server. We just rebuilt with our Prod server version: 7.0.0.00.20160215-1938 with the same results.

Comment: In this case note that a similar error was identified in an active PMR which a fix for is being tested; consider opening a PMR as well.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930397/direct-update-failure-in-mobilefirst-application-7-0 ??

Has no one been able to update their application using 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in which the content type of returned direct update zip is not "application/zip" as it should be.

Note that Worklight server returns "application/zip" content type for android direct update. We have a test fix right now where we just log the different content type and continue the direct update process since it can be correct zip and content type can be changed by firewall for example.

If you create a PMR, we can give you a test fix to test (just drop worklight-android.jar into Android project -> deploy onto device). Once we confirm that it works we can deliver it to production builds. When submitting the PMR please link them to this StackOverflow question to give full background of issue.

Comment: we've created a PMR #81385,442,000 can you please send us the file to test. Pat Barron is our IBM coordinator.

Comment: We updated the jar file and deployed to server and device. Still fails and same error message still exits.

NOTE: This also fails for iphone environment/device.